# How to Prove a Riemann Surface is Hyperbolic by Showing its Volume Grows Exponentially?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, complex-manifolds

We have a **Holomorphic Foliation by curves** on a **Complex Manifold**. Therefore, every leaf is a Riemann Surface.

Let $R$ be a **Riemann Surface**.

We say that the Riemann Surface $R$ is **Hyperbolic** if and only if one of the two following equivalent conditions is satisfied:

1. $R$ is isomorphic to a quotient of the **Upper Half-Plane** by a **Fuchsian Group**.
2. Its covering space is isomorphic to the **Hyperbolic Disk**.

Meanwhile, it is mentioned that to prove that the Riemann Surface $R$ is Hyperbolic *it is sufficient to prove its volume grows exponentially*.

What does that mean?

(Or, How to define the **Volume** of the Riemann Surface $R$, and to find out whether or not the volume grows exponentially?).

Comment: Where is it mentioned?

Comment: The trouble is that this sentence is ill-defined since a Riemann surface is not the same as a Riemannian surface. I suspect, the intended meaning is: Suppose that $S$ is a complete Riemannian surface of exponential area growth. Then $S$ is of hyperbolic type in the sense of the potential theory. But there could be other meanings. As written, the question is ill-posed. Voting to close.

Comment: @MoisheKohan We have a Holomorphic Foliation by curves on a Complex Manifold. Therefore, every leaf is a Riemann Surface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll use the word "area" instead of "volume", since we are in 2 dimensions.

The [Uniformization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) implies that there exists a complete Riemannian metric on $R$ in the given conformal class with constant curvature $\kappa = -1$, $0$ or $+1$. Furthermore, that metric is unique if $\kappa = -1$ or $+1$, and it is unique up to scaling if $\kappa = 0$. Area on $R$ is defined using the area form of that metric.

In the case $\kappa = 1$, $R$ is a sphere and has finite area.

In the case $\kappa = 0$, $R$ is either a torus which has finite area, a cylinder which has linearly growing area, or the Euclidean plane which has quadratically growing area.

It follows that if the area of $R$ grows exponentially then $\kappa = -1$.

Comment: But what does "the area grows quadratically/exponentially" actually mean? Do you consider a ball of fixed radius and translate it to infinity?

Comment: This is a standard definition in Riemannian geometry, it refers to the growth of the function $r \mapsto \text{Area}(B(p,r))$, where $p \in R$ is chosen arbitrarily and $B(p,r)$ denotes the ball in $R$ of radius $r$ around $p$.